# Unreachable code in swtch statement

Tags: java

I have written following method in Java. But I get error message unreachable code on the line containing return (Constants.SUCCESS);

If I comment that line, I do not get error message. Now my doubt is why I do not get error message if I comment that line? There is no return value of SUCCESS to the calling portion if I comment the line. I thought there should be one return statement and there are none if all "if loops" and default is not getting executed. I thought last return statement will execute in any case. I tried return (Constants.SUCCESS) statement at the end also (Commented line), but no luck.
So for returning success, do I need to return success after each "if" loop under every case statements (creating "else" part for each).

```
static int validateStartAndEndStringOrder(String startStr, String endStr, ArrayList<String> swaraPool, Constants.PatternType ptrnType) {
        switch (ptrnType) {
            case AROHA_INCREASING: {
                if (swaraPool.indexOf(endStr) < swaraPool.indexOf(startStr)) {
                    System.out.println("End string is before the start String");
                    return (-1);
                }
            }
            case AROHA_DECREASING: {
                if (swaraPool.indexOf(startStr) < swaraPool.indexOf(endStr)) {
                    System.out.println("End string is before the start String");
                    return (-1);
                }
            }
            case AVAROHA_INCREASING: {
                if (swaraPool.indexOf(endStr) < swaraPool.indexOf(startStr)) {
                    System.out.println("End string is before the start String");
                    return (-1);
                }
            }
            case AVAROHA_DECREASING: {
                if (swaraPool.indexOf(startStr) < swaraPool.indexOf(endStr)) {
                    System.out.println("End string is before the start String");
                    return (-1);
                }
            }
              default: {
                System.out.println("Invalid Enumeration Type");
                return(-1);
            }
              return (Constants.SUCCESS);
        }
//return (Constants.SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want to add a `break;` at the end of your `case` blocks.  Otherwise the code just runs from top to bottom (like anywhere else in your code)

If you place a `break;` it will jump outside the `switch` block which appears to be what you want.

e.g.

```
       case AROHA_INCREASING: {
            if (swaraPool.indexOf(endStr) < swaraPool.indexOf(startStr)) {
                System.out.println("End string is before the start String");
                return (-1);
            }
            break; // without this, the thread will run the next case: block.
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

`switch ... case 1 ... case n ... default` covers all control paths (the `default` will catch all remaining cases). Since you return explicitly out of each one, there's no way program control can go beyond that `switch` block.

Your compiler is being helpful in emitting the error.

Use `break;` statements between each `case` in the `switch` block to move control flow to the end of the block.

Answer (score 1):

You default section contains

```
{
    System.out.println("Invalid Enumeration Type");
    return(-1);
}
return (Constants.SUCCESS);
```

What do you expect?